# I can use a timestamp variable on query of cursor in a store procedure?

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I need a  timestamp variable that whill change dinamicaly, but when i try pass this timestamp variable  to statement , this doesn't  work:

without a timestamp variable ,it works:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE "PR_TEST"( sl_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)  
IS
    stm VARCHAR2(3000);
    var_ativo number:= 1 ;
BEGIN
    stm := 'SELECT
               *
        FROM
            SIMET.TB_1 SC
            JOIN SIMET.TB_2 D ON D.HASH = SC.HASH
        WHERE
             SC.IS_ACTIVE = ' || var_ativo ;            
     OPEN sl_cursor FOR  stm ;
END;
```

but with the timestamp var , it doesnt work:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE "PR_TEST"( sl_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)  
IS
    stm VARCHAR2(3000);
    var_ativo number:= 1 ;
    var_ts timestamp := SYSTIMESTAMP
BEGIN
    stm := 'SELECT
               *
        FROM
            SIMET.TB_1 SC
            JOIN SIMET.TB_2 D ON D.HASH = SC.HASH
        WHERE
             SC.IS_ACTIVE = ' || var_ativo 
         AND 
             sc.timestamp = ' || var_ts

     OPEN sl_cursor FOR  stm ;
END;
```

Someone knows how i could do it?

Comment: Neither of these queries appear to require dynamic SQL.  Are you really, really, really sure that you need a dynamic SQL approach rather than just using static SQL?

Comment: Have you tried GetDate() ? Why are you using Dymanic SQL rather than just straight up SQL?

Comment: I'm using dynamic sql for this because my complete query spend so many time just to return the select, and after the select i need to do the update in each result, ( about 3 milion ) and the database stop . then i decided  to separate in smaller queries and i will do a loop that i wil change the date , day by day.  Someone Will suggest another approach?

Comment: Sorry about my (poor) English, i'm studding to improve this.

Comment: This doesn't even look like t-sql is this a CLR proc? Why would you use one for something that can be done in t-sql? Running an update on 3 million records one at a time in a proc is a very bad idea. You may still need to loop but you want to run in batches of records not a typical cursor of one record at a time.  Please give more definition about what exactly you are trying to accomplish so we can show you the best way to get there. Currently there is not enough information to figure out what you need because you reference an update after a select and don't show us the code for that.

Comment: Thank the helpof every one . the aswer below worked  and I create this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35506324/what-i-must-use-dynamic-sql-static-sql-or-other-solution-in-oracle-database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate problem is that you aren't concatenating your string properly; you need to have the `AND` as part of the literal too. And you're missing a semicolon.

```
stm := 'SELECT
           *
    FROM
        SIMET.TB_1 SC
        JOIN SIMET.TB_2 D ON D.HASH = SC.HASH
    WHERE
         SC.IS_ACTIVE = ' || var_ativo || '
     AND 
         sc.timestamp = ' || var_ts;
```

But now you are implicitly converting your `v_ts` variable to a string. As a string it would need to be enclosed in escaped single quotes:

```
         sc.timestamp = ''' || var_ts || '''';
```

But that involves more implicit conversion to compare with the column values so really you'd want to explicitly convert it both ways. Which, as you might imagine, is a bit of a red-flag that you're doing something wrong.

If you are using dynamic SQL then you should use bind variables:

```
stm := 'SELECT
           *
    FROM
        SIMET.TB_1 SC
        JOIN SIMET.TB_2 D ON D.HASH = SC.HASH
    WHERE
         SC.IS_ACTIVE = :ativo
     AND 
         sc.timestamp = :ts';

 OPEN sl_cursor FOR stm USING var_ativo, var_ts;
```

But from what you've shown you should not be using dynamic SQL here at all:

```
 OPEN sl_cursor FOR
    SELECT
           *
    FROM
        SIMET.TB_1 SC
        JOIN SIMET.TB_2 D ON D.HASH = SC.HASH
    WHERE
         SC.IS_ACTIVE = var_ativo 
     AND 
         sc.timestamp = var_ts;
```

To quote Tom Kyte: "[You use dynamic sql only when there is quite simply NO WAY to do it statically.](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:5243903111288)"

Your premise that splitting whatever you're doing into smaller queries and updates is probably incorrect, and you're likely to be making it slower overall; but that's a separate issue and something that would need a lot more information to address.

Comment: Thank you for the help. This worked. But I created this new question to try find a better solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35506324/what-i-must-use-dynamic-sql-static-sql-or-other-solution-in-oracle-database