# What should I use: dynamic SQL, static SQL or other solution in Oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm senior JEE developer but I really new in PL/SQL development and i need help from seniors Oracle developers.

My problem is:

I need update 3 million of rows in database.

I made a procedure that worked so well in laboratory database.

But in production database, this is really slow and i really dont want lock the database.

The first trying was  create this procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE "PR_UPDATE_R" AS
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('1.Find measures...') ; 
    FOR obj IN (
        SELECT SC.ID ID
        FROM SIMET.TB_SC SC
        JOIN SIMET.TB_D D ON D.HASH = SC.HASH
        JOIN (
            SELECT
                T1.ID_D_FK,
                MIN (T1.UPDATE_DATE) LIMIT_DATE
            FROM
                TB_SBVH T1
            WHERE
                T1. VERSION > 10000
            GROUP BY
                T1.ID_D_FK
        ) SBVH ON SBVH.ID_D_FK = D .ID_D_PK
        WHERE
        (
            SBVH.LIMIT_DATE IS NULL OR  SC.TIMESTAMP_CREATION < SBVH.LIMIT_DATE
        )       
        AND 
            sc.TIMESTAMP_CREATION >= TO_TIMESTAMP ('2012-08-27 00:00:00.000000','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.ff')
        AND 
            sc.MEASURE_TIMESTAMP_CREATION <= TO_TIMESTAMP ('2015-07-06 00:00:00.00000','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.ff')
)LOOP
    UPDATE TB_R SET total = total + other_field WHERE id_m_fk = obj.ID ; 
    UPDATE tb_sc
        SET TOTAL_PCT = (
            SELECT
                CASE WHEN SUM (r.total_sent) > 0 THEN (
                    100 * SUM (r.total_lost) / SUM (r.total_sent)
                )
                ELSE
                    0
                END
            FROM
                tb_r r
            WHERE
                ID = obj.ID
        )
    WHERE
        ID = obj.ID;
END LOOP; 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('2.Finished!!!') ;
END ;
```

But was not a good Idea , because the main query of this procedure (into the FOR loop), alone, spent 29 minutes!! locking database .

Then,

My second idea was share the main query in small ones , kind of bach, and run it with small loops.

This new query running  each day per time  , spend  3 seconds.

And , the idea is : i put this fast diary query into a loop and run with 30 a 30 days each time:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            SC.ID_M_FK,
            SC.TIMESTAMP_CREATION,
            D.ID_D_PK
        FROM
            TB_SC SC
            JOIN TB_D D ON D.HASH = SC.HASH
        WHERE
                SC.TIMESTAMP_CREATION >= TIMESTAMP '2013-02-06 00:00:00.000'
            AND SC.TIMESTAMP_CREATION <  TIMESTAMP '2013-02-07 00:00:00.000'
            AND SC.IS_ACTIVE = 1
    ) CD -- CACHE_DATA
    JOIN (
        SELECT
            T1.ID_D_FK,
            MIN (T1.UPDATE_DATE) LIMIT_DATE
        FROM
            TB_SBVH T1
        WHERE
            T1. VERSION > 10000
        GROUP BY
            T1.ID_D_FK
    ) SBVH ON SBVH.ID_D_FK = CD.ID_D_PK
WHERE
    (
        SBVH.LIMIT_DATE IS NULL
        OR
        CD.TIMESTAMP_CREATION < SBVH.LIMIT_DATE
    )
;
```

But in this  question  [I can use a timestamp variable on query of cursor in a store procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35491776/i-can-use-a-timestamp-variable-on-query-of-cursor-in-a-store-procedure/35493128#35493128)
many people tell me that it is not a good solution.

Someone could help me please?

Comment: Why are you doing this in PL/SQl at all, and row-by-row updates? Why not a single SQL update statement, which would be much more efficient?

Comment: I could try this, but to do a single SQL update statement with my query that spent 29 minutes to select the data is it a good idea?

Comment: If the data volume in both your laboratory db and production are the same and the indexes are the same, check the stats on the table, it might be too old or never done. Most of the time the execution plan is different. There are ways to force a plan too. But check the stats and the plan. It will give you clues to what to do. Depending on the # of processors and resources, Oracle can easily handle 3M rows. So most likely you may not have to change your code. But as Alex mentioned above single update statement or BULK updates are better.

Comment: I would first investigate why your query takes 29 minutes. As mentioned this may be due to wrong statistics or perhaps you have to tune your query. Perhaps it is legitimate that the query just runs so long because of the amount of the data, then I would look at a batched approach or PARALLEL query if you have the luxury of Enterprise Edition, but never, ever do Row-By-Row updates. It will never perform nor scale!

Comment: Hello! Thank you every one for try help me.  
But like gbenzi told:  Row-By-Row updates takes a lot of time  and it's never performs. I tried  a single sql update statement  like Alex Poole told me and have the same problem that PL/SQL.
We have Enterprise Edition, then I will take a look about  bulk, batched approach and  PARALLEL query .